# The word for someone who lectures that "there's a wrong way and a right way"

Tags: word-choice

I'm looking for a word for a person who lectures others, on a trivial topic, telling them that "there's a right way and a wrong way" to do things.

A couple of words come to mind: "rigid", "finicky". But those don't adequately capture how trivial the person's lecturing is.

Comment: They're either opinionated, wrong, or correct.

Comment: What is “how trivial the person’s lecturing is” supposed to mean? It seemingly plays an important role in the question, since it’s the reason you’ve rejected _rigid_, which I would have thought was perfectly fine; but it makes no sense whatsoever. What’s trivial about claiming that there is a wrong way and a right way to do something? In some cases, that will be true; in others not. Either way, triviality doesn’t seem to be related. And are we talking about an actual teacher giving a lecture, or about someone just ‘lecturing’ people around them in a broader sense?

Comment: I find it amusing that `In some cases, that will be true; in others not.` is made trivial by the next sentence. `Either way, triviality doesn't seem to be related.`

Comment: If both the right way and the wrong way have "trivial" differences between them and end up with the same result, then arguing that you should do things the right way could also be considered trivial by some people.

Comment: **Prescriptive**: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prescriptive

Comment: The word would be "[Corrigan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Corrigan)".

Answer (score 8):

A [pedant](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pedant?searchDictCode=all) or being [pedantic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pedantic?searchDictCode=all) springs to mind the most as capturing triviality. But also [dogmatic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dogmatic), [opinionated](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/opinionated), or [doctrinaire](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/doctrinaire).

Answer (score 3):

A [martinet](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/martinet) is someone who demands strict adherence to rules. A [stickler](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stickler) is similar.

In both cases the implication is that these people believe procedure should be followed regardless of how little benefit it might have in a particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

When applied to a person (can be the self or others), this is called 'polarised' or 'black-and-white' thinking:

> Cognitive Distortions: 2. Polarized Thinking (or “Black and White” Thinking).
>
> In polarized thinking, things are either “black-or-white.” We have to be perfect or we’re a failure — there is no middle ground. You place people or situations in “either/or” categories, with no shades of gray or allowing for the complexity of most people and situations. If your performance falls short of perfect, you see yourself as a total failure.

[15 Common Cognitive Distortions](http://psychcentral.com/lib/15-common-cognitive-distortions/0002153), John Grohol, PsychCentral

As I currently read a lot (a *lot*) of "Thomas the Tank Engine" books to my little girl, your question also made me think of [Fergus](http://ttte.wikia.com/wiki/Fergus), who typifies this personality trait for 3-year-olds:

> Fergus knows the rulebook off by heart, and his catchphrase is "Do it right!" His insistence on doing everything absolutely according to the rules can annoy the other engines, but he is a decent engine at heart ...

so we could talk about an 'insistence on following the rulebook'. '[Nagging](http://www.sodor-island.net/railwayprofiles.html)' is also a possibility:

> He is known to be a strict engine, knowing every rule and regulation by heart, and is constantly nagging the other engines to “Do It Right!”

A word which captures the petty nature of this trait (although not the black/white thinking) is 'niggling':

> **niggle**
>
> 1.1 VERB [WITH OBJECT] Criticize or annoy (someone) in a petty way

[niggle. Oxford Dictionaries. Oxford University Press, n.d. Web. 16 January 2015.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/niggle)

Overall I'd go with something like "**a petty, niggling insistence on following the rulebook**". The word 'corrosive' can also be useful for criticising criticism which is excessively harsh or unconstructive.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean a "fussbudget," which [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fussbudget) defines like this:

> one who fusses or is fussy especially about trifles